# Removing entry Date in sparkR

Tags: r, sparkr

I have a DataFrame x. It contains ID and Date. So

```
head(x)
```

gives ID = 1 2 ... and Date = "2012-05-05" "2015-01-01" ...

I want to make a new data-set where all ID's with Date higher than "2013-01-01" + P are removed. P is day for example P = 3 days.

In sparkR I do this

```
newdata <- filter(x, x$Date < as.Date(2013-01-01 + P) )
```

but sparkR does not accept this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say "sparkR does not accept this", you should elaborate. Is there an error? What is the error? Or does the code run without error, but not give the desired result? In this case, what does it give?

You have a number of fairly trivial syntax errors.

- use `subset`, not `filter`. Tip: `?filter` shows you that this function "applies linear filtering to a univariate time series", where "filtering" doesn't mean filter in the sense of 'subset', but in the sense of 'convolution'
- when you `as.Date`, your dates should be surrounded in quote marks. Add the `P` to the date, not within the date constructor. As a hint:

  ```
  as.Date(2013-01-01)
  Error in as.Date.numeric(2013 - 1 - 1) : 'origin' must be supplied
  ```

  Note this is trying to convert '2013 - 1 - 1', i.e. the **number** 2011. And it says `as.Date.numeric` whereas you want to supply the string "2013-01-01". When you try this, it works:

  ```
  as.Date("2013-01-01")
  # [1] "2013-01-01"
  ```

  Then add your 3 and `subset`. As an aside, in `subset` you don't need to supply the `x$` in front of `Date` (see `?subset`):

  ```
  subset(x, Date < as.Date("2013-01-01") + 3)
  ```

Moral of the story: post all errors received when asking questions, try work through your code bit by bit (if the entire line of code doesn't work, try breaking it down in to the smallest bits that work so you can resolve your problems one at a time).

Comment: Thanks for the response. In sparkR I must write x$Date instead of Date in the 'subset' command otherwise 'Date' can not be found. When I use the subset command then sparkR tells me 'subset must be logical'. When I use 'filter'-command it works fine. For me I didnt know that as.Date("2013-01-01") + 3 was adding 3 to the date as days and not years for example.

Comment: Cheers, I did not realise `sparkR` overwrote `filter`. (That is why it is useful to post the error messages you get with your question...)

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @mathematical.coffee, you should put P outside the as.Date, but in contrary to what he says, in SparkR you should use filter, hence the following is working code:

```
# Create x and set it to a data
x2 <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2),
                 Date=c("2012-05-05","2015-01-01"))
x2$Date <- as.Date(x2$Date)
x <- createDataFrame(sqlContext,x2)

# set P and compare the dates
P <- 2
newdata <- filter(x, x$Date < (as.Date("2013-01-01")+P) )

# See the first results (in my example only one row)
head(newdata)
```